# Waiting a year before applying semi-solid stain to new treated pine deck?

Tags: deck, stain, pressure-treated

We had a new pressure-treated pine deck installed about six months ago.
I know the wood has aged/dried enough to take a semi-ttransparent stain.

But we prefer the appearance of a semi-solid stain like Cabot's or Armstrong & Clark's.
The instructions from Armstrong & Clark say you should wait at least a year before using their semi-solid stain.

I guess I don't know what to do in the meantime?
Should we just leave it unfinished, or should we apply a semi-transparent stain then apply the semi-solid one after another year has gone by?

I'm pretty confused! Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Wow, I don’t think I have waited a year but I only use pressure treated for the  structural. I would probably wait until mid summer but I would not wait until fall because by then two much rain in Oregon.

Comment: We built a deck out of PT pine in the fall and waited nearly a year before sealing it (no stain), mostly out of poor timing on the weather and some laziness. It had turned a rather nasty grey by then and required pressure washing to get the top surface to look a nice brown color again. Unfortunately, no matter how careful I was, I still couldn't get it to a consistent color. I would recommend _not_ waiting a full year or you may end up with needing to pressure wash yours, too.